# folder path in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

```
//this does not work 

  function resize(imagepath,cb){
            var app = ComFiles.app;
            var originalMime ;

        jimp.read(imagepath,function(err,image){
            //get original mimetype
            originalMime = image && image._originalmime ;
            cb(err,image);
        });
}

function caller(cb){
    var path = "D:\\a\\b\\c\\images\\605322.jpg";
    resize(path,function(err,result){
        cb(err,result);
    })
}

//but hard-coding path like this works
  function resize(imagepath,cb){
            var app = ComFiles.app;

            var originalMime ;

            jimp.read("D:\\a\\b\\c\\images\\605322.jpg",function(err,image){
                //get original mimetype
                originalMime = image && image._originalmime ;
                callback(err,image);
            });
    }
```

I am trying to read this image using JIMP library. `imagepath` can be accessed by fs module, but jimp somehow escapes the slashes and the file is not read. If i hard-code the `imagepath` , then it gets read. What could be the problem and how do I get it fixed ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "If I hard-code the `imagepath`, then it gets read." Could you share the working code so we can compare it to the code that doesn't work? (I'm assuming the code in your question does not work.)

Comment: i have edited code to include piece of actual code

Comment: In both cases, you seem to be trying to call a function called `callback` which doesn't exist. Are you sure this is the exact code you're using? And when you say "this does not work," what do you mean specifically? Do you see an error? If so, please share it.

Comment: callback exists. i have pasted a piece of my code here.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to be able to help if you don't share actual working code and the error you're receiving.